# Invoke-Async to deploy SQL script on multiple servers.

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use **invoke-Async** to deploy a SQL script to multiple sql servers.

The invoke-async code is [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Invoke-Async-Allows-you-to-83b0c9f0).
The script uses invoke-sqlcmd2, the code for which is [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/7985b7ef-ed89-4dfd-b02a-433cc4e30894).

The following non-sql-server-code works.

```
$sb = [scriptblock] {param($system) gwmi win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $system | select csname,caption} 
$servers = 'Server1', 'Server2', 'Server3', 'Server4'
$rtn = Invoke-Async -Set $servers -SetParam system  -ScriptBlock $sb
$rtn
```

I tweaked the code a bit (below) to work for SQL server. Doesn't work. Obviously, I'm missing something. Any help is greately appreciated. Thank you.

```
$sb = [scriptblock] {param($system) Invoke-SQLCmd2 -ServerInstance $system -ServerInstance 'select name from sys.databases'  } 
$servers = 'Server1', 'Server2', 'Server3', 'Server4' 
$rtn = Invoke-Async -Set $servers -SetParam system  -ScriptBlock $sb
$rtn
```

Comment: There is no default command for powershell Invoke-Async. But there is a function available. You should be getting the error that Invoke-Async is not recognized as a cmdlet. Please post the error

Comment: I have already downloaded a copy of invoke-sync, as i mentioned in my post. I don't get "Invoke-Async is not recognized as a cmdlet" exception. I'm just unable to use Invoke-sqlcmd2 with Invoke-sync. Is invoke-async working for you with invoke-sqlcmd2?

Comment: Invoke-sqlcmd2 also is an external function which by default won't be there..if u want to use it then put the entire function definition inside the script block then call it

Comment: Please read my post carefully, I know both functions are not native. I have used both functions in the same script. Please try the code at your end and see if it works for you. Gosh, this looks like 'reputation' generating thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple. Since you are returning rows. Just use invoke-sqlcmd.. 
Not sure if invoke-Async will return tables when using invoke-sqlcmd2 -As DataTable.

```
      $sb = [scriptblock] {param($system) Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $system -query 'select name from sys.databases' }  
      $servers =  'Server1', 'Server2', 'Server3' 
      $rtn = Invoke-Async -Set $servers -SetParam system  -ScriptBlock $sb -Verbose       
      $rtn
```

Comment: Thank you Rahim, That worked. Here are the things I learned. 
1. I should have used Invoke-SQLCMD (instead of invoke-sqlcmd2)
2. I used -SERVERINSTANCE twice in my example. That was a type. The second one should have been -QUERY.